# targeting more than one following element with element+element

Tags: css, css-selectors

What I want to do is target more than one `<p>` with the following code:

```
h1+p
{
    margin-left: 20px;
}

h2+p
{
    margin-left: 27px;
}

h3+p
{
    margin-left: 35px;
}
```

Below is the effect I am trying to achieve:

[image: The effect]

The problem is that when there is a new `<p>` element, the block of text is obviously going to revert to it's normal position, without the margin, and not longer inline with the heading.

(like so)

[image: The issue]

Is there a better way of attacking this problem? (or one that works for that matter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/chrismackie/5DgNH/

Comment: Yes, this is the concept of what I am trying to do. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can *somewhat* achieve this by using the general sibling selector `~` instead of the adjacent sibling selector `+`:

```
h1~p
{
    margin-left: 20px;
}

h2~p
{
    margin-left: 27px;
}

h3~p
{
    margin-left: 35px;
}
```

Be careful with this, though, especially if your `h1`, `h2`, `h3` and `p` elements all share the same parent. Due to the way that styles cascade as well as how sibling selectors work, all your `p` elements that follow the last `h3` element will get the 35-pixel margin, even if the last heading in your container is an `h1` or `h2`.

For instance, if you have this Markdown:

```
# Heading 1

Paragraph

Paragraph

## Heading 2

Paragraph

Paragraph

### Heading 3

Paragraph

Paragraph

## Heading 2

Paragraph

Paragraph
```

The *last four* paragraphs will have a 35-pixel margin, including the two that follow your last `h2`, because your `h3~p` rule is the last in the cascading order and all your elements share the same parent. This may or may not be the effect you're trying to achieve (I'm guessing it's not).

There isn't a pure CSS workaround for this, I'm afraid; you're going to have to post-process the rendered markup with JavaScript to add classes and such to your paragraphs based on your headings.

Comment: This did occur to me, but the issue of cascading makes it not usable, they need to be inline with `x` heading until the next heading, because there are nested headings. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: In that case, you won't be able to achieve this with pure CSS.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I would have liked to keep this clean and pure CSS.

thanks for the help anyway.