# CSS General Sibling Selector Specificity

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

For a document:

```
<h1>Section 1</h1>
<p>I came after a h1 and should be red.</p>
<p>I came after a h1 and should be red.</p>

<h2>Section 2</h2>
<p>I came after a h2 and should be green.</p>
<p>I came after a h2 and should be green.</p>

<h1>Section 3</h1>
<p>I should be the same color as the section one text?</p>
<p>I should be the same color as the section one text?</p>
```

I tried to style it:

```
h1 ~ p {
    color: red;
}

h2 ~ p {
    color: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ks7j938/7/

I expected that paragraphs 1 and 3 would have the same style, with the third paragraph matching against the more specific `h1 ~ p` selector because a `h1` is a closer sibling than a `h2`. However, in my testing, the result is that paragraphs 2 and 3 are styled the same.

Two questions:

Does the css selector spec actually specify this behavior somewhere? The [css spec on the General sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) seems open to interpretation here.

How can I achieve the intended result of having paragraphs 1 and 3 styled the same way? I cannot add classes or any attributes to the html, I can only control the css.

Comment: The section on [calculating selector specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) never mentions combinators, so it is safe to assume or even infer that combinators have no effect on selector specificity.

Comment: As for achieving the intended result, Musa is right: you won't be able to do so with pure CSS given your document structure. Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427998/targeting-more-than-one-following-element-with-elementelement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330757/target-all-general-siblings-before-next-occurance-of-same-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both selectors have the same specificity, what causes `h2 ~ p` to take precedence is that it is defined after, therefore cascading over `h1 ~ p`. How close the sibling are is of no consequence.
For the behavior you want you can use the [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) `+`.

If you change the `h1 ~ p` after you will see it takes precidience

```css
h2 ~ p {
    color: green;
}

h1 ~ p {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Section 1</h1>
<p>I came after a h1 and should be red.</p>
    
<h2>Section 2</h2>
<p>I came after a h2 and should be green.</p>

<h1>Section 3</h1>
<p>I should be the same color as the section one text?</p>
```

Comment: You just beat me to it :p

Comment: Your ordering explanation makes sense (but still not what I expected). But your adjacent sibling selector solution does not work, or rather it works just well enough to solve the very limited example problem originally posted. It does not work with multiple elements per section, but I've updated the jsfiddle and example.

Comment: @MattBierner I cannot think of a general purpose for solution for your problem, I would just use `h1+p,h1+p+p,h1...` for how many ever `p` there could be

Comment: @AbdelrahmanGobarah The snippet is to demonstrate behavior explained in the answer and hence works exactly as intended.

Answer (score 3):

Musa seems to be correct that you can't solve this in the general case using only CSS.

But here's one solution for three sections:

```
h1 ~ p,
h1 ~ h1 ~ p {
    color: red;
}

h2 ~ p {
    color: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ks7j938/12/

Or, depending of the number of interleavings, this may also work and could possibly be extended to more sections:

```
h1 ~ p,
h1 ~ h2 ~ h1 ~ p,
h1 ~ h2 ~ h1 ~ h2 ~ h1 ~ p
/* add more as needed */ {
    color: red;
}

h2 ~ p,
h2 ~ h1 ~ h2 ~ p,
h2 ~ h1 ~ h2 ~ h1 ~ h2  ~ p
/* add more as needed */ {
    color: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ks7j938/15/

Neither approach is particularly scalable however.

Answer (score 1):

what a tricky question! 
If you have access to add some jQuery, then some [traversing methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) might be of use.
The following works, but you would need to make it fit your specific needs, so another method may be better.

```
$( "h1" )
  .nextUntil( "h2" )
    .css( "color", "red" );

$( "h2" )
  .nextUntil("h1")
    .css( "color", "green" );
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ks7j938/11/)

Comment: The question asked is a basic misunderstanding of CSS selectors and specificity. Your answer is ‘screw it let’s use JavaScript’ rather than try to actually understand what’s going on in CSS.

Comment: Some of the other answers already give insight to how this problem might be solved with CSS. I found this jQuery method actually solves this specific question, and suggest there may be other alternatives too. Im not saying screw it, i'm just offering another possible solution. build a bridge.

Answer (score 0):

your code have css of `h1` tag in very first line so it will look for all `p`tag which is siblings to that `h1` tag and will apply red color to all `p` tag. at the very next line it will find two `p` tag which are below first 'h1`tag and those two`p` tag will be applied second css. This is an excate problem that you have. **now solution to your problem is css3** [adjecent siblings selector](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/adjacent-sibling-selector-css-selector/)

**Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ks7j938/9/**

Comment: See the updated example with many elements per section for why adjacent selectors do not work for more general cases: http://jsfiddle.net/4ks7j938/10/

Answer (score -1):

**You can use this code:**

```
h1 ~ p {
    color: red; 
}
h2+p{
    color: green; 
}
```